# APIGEE lookup cache is not working for subsequent requests

Tags: apigee

I am new to APIGEE. I am trying to implement a populate cache and lookup cache usecase.

From my test, I am not able to populate cache and lookup cache in subsequent request. However just for testing if I lookup cache within the same request I get a successful hit. So my setup is

Lookup cache --> service callout --> populate cache --> lookup cache

The first lookup cache is always false and the second lookup cache is true for every request. My expectation is the first lookup cache should return a cache hit after the first request.

Can you please provide me guidance on what could be wrong.

**First lookup**

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-1.cachekey     vouchers__9344401449022

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-1.cachehit     false

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-1.failed   false

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-1.cachename    woolworths__test__edr_customer_cache

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-1.assignto     voucherjson

**Second Lookup**

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-2.cachename    woolworths__test__edr_customer_cache

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-2.assignto     flowvar

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-2.cachekey     vouchers__9344401449022

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-2.failed   false

lookupcache.Lookup-Cache-2.cachehit     true

Lookup policy (same for both)

```
<CacheKey>
  <Prefix>vouchers</Prefix>
  <KeyFragment ref="edrno" />
</CacheKey>
<CacheResource>edr_customer_cache</CacheResource>
<Scope>Global</Scope>
```

Comment: On further testing, I found that once in a while I get a valid cache hit on the first lookup. Approximately only 2 in 10 requests return "true" for cache hit. Does this mean something is wrong with the environment.

Comment: I'm also encountering this at the moment. It will either return a cachehit value of true or false across multiple request,all the while it should always be true, why is this happening though?. My Scope is Global as this cache must be accessed across different proxies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem description suggests that the cache is not propagating across different message processors. That's why you see the cache lookup successful in the same request but not across multiple requests. Also you need not have lookup cache policy before and after the populate cache. I would also suggest you try changing the scope from global to Exclusive and see if that works.

How big is the response that you are trying to cache. That would also give us an idea of what's going on.